# Some postdoc positions do not have deadlines, but will open until filled. What is happening?

Tags: application, job-search, university, postdocs

I am currently searching for postdoc positions for my first time. Many postdoc positions have definite deadlines, but others don't. Surprisingly, some prestigious institutes list postdoc positions for a long time but they are still waiting for applicants. My belief is that prestigious institutes would quickly receive a lot of applications, so that the positions ought to be taken very soon, but this appears to not be the case. What is happening?

Comment: They wait for good (or better, great) applicants. Finding the right one can take quite a while, and they can afford to be picky.

Answer (score 6):

Long story short, they don't need to "settle for less". Though this may sound somewhat crass, the truth of the matter is that many elite institutions probably do receive a large number of applications but reject most of them. Because there is no risk of the supply of interested applicants disappearing, a lab can wait to pick out a candidate that they feel meets their (possibly very high) requirements.

Comment: feel more pressure now :)